# Failed to create 'E:\HashMap\workspace\YbyUser\bin\YbyUser.apks': Access denied

Tags: java, android, eclipse

> Description    Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   Error generating final archive: Failed to create 'E:\HashMap\workspace\YbyUser\bin\User.apks': Access denied。   YbyUser     Unknown Android Packaging Problem

Each time you run eclipse will appear this mistake.I want to know how to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-)
Please look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Run the program as an administrator. Make sure that the file permissions are configured correctly on the E: drive. If it is a mobile phone or tablet, it may need to be unlocked by your pin/password/pattern.